# Should autoload.php be included in class files

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, plivo

We're using this plivo package: https://github.com/plivo/plivo-php and the current version is throwing an error because it can't find the autoload file which they're requiring at the top of their class file.

```
<?php
namespace Plivo;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Guzzle\Http\Client;
class PlivoError extends \Exception {}
```

From my experience the autoload file should only be included in the page that's actually going to be calling class's and functions.

Is this an error on their end or is there some way we can fix this within our own project that will persist through `composer updates`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now fixed in my pull request for this library.

Indeed it is wrong to reference any composer autoloading in a package itself. Composer will install a globally available autoloader that is able to load every class included in any `composer.json` description.

Comment: Thanks. I've never done a pull request before or else I probably would have just done that myself. Next time I will!

Comment: @Sven Please check your pull request, it seams there is garbage at the end of the file

Comment: For easy stuff this is completely easy, because Github has an online editor - it is basically some typing/deleting and two clicks for saving and creating the PR.

Comment: @clemens321: Maybe thousand lines won't fit into that online editor. :( This is an example how PRs can go wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

So I made a new directory to test this out:

```
[~/Code/plivo/php]$ mkdir composer_testing
[~/Code/plivo/php]$ cd composer_testing/
```

and initialized a new `composer.json` file with no dependencies:

```
[~/Code/plivo/php/composer_testing]$ composer init


Welcome to the Composer config generator 



This command will guide you through creating your composer.json config.

Package name (<vendor>/<name>) [charlie/composer_testing]: 
Description []: 
Author [Charlie Chrisman <charlie@plivo.com>]: 
Minimum Stability []: 
Package Type []: 
License []: 

Define your dependencies.

Would you like to define your dependencies (require) interactively [yes]? n
Would you like to define your dev dependencies (require-dev) interactively [yes]? n

{
    "name": "charlie/composer_testing",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Charlie Chrisman",
            "email": "charlie@plivo.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {}
}

Do you confirm generation [yes]?
```

and then required the plivo-php library (that has the `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` line)

```
[~/Code/plivo/php/composer_testing]$ composer require plivo/plivo-php
Using version ^1.0 for plivo/plivo-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
- Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.7.6)
Loading from cache

- Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (v3.8.1)
Loading from cache

- Installing plivo/plivo-php (v1.0.0)
Loading from cache

symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/http-kernel ()
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
[~/Code/plivo/php/composer_testing]$
```

and here is the updated composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "charlie/composer_testing",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Charlie Chrisman",
            "email": "charlie@plivo.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "plivo/plivo-php": "^1.0"
    }
}
```

and then wrote a simple php file for generating a text to speech XML:

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$r = new Plivo\Response();

$message = "Testing Plivo";
$params = array(
    'language' => "en-US",
    'voice' => 'WOMAN'
);

$r->addSpeak($message, $params);
Header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo($r->toXML());

?>
```

and it correctly outputs the expected XML

```
<Response>
    <Speak language="en-US" voice="WOMAN">Testing Plivo</Speak>
</Response>
```

Why is it working for me and not for you?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work for me but I'm using config-dir in composer to change the location of the vendor folder to fit with legacy code. This hasn't caused any issues with any other package. When I do the same thing with your test the error pops up.